# Laravel Eloquent Model scope multiple criteria

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, scope, model, eloquent

I have a question regarding the definition of a scope in my Laravel Eloquent Model

Situation:
Model is 'Subscription', which has a.o. attributes 'startdate' and 'enddate'. Startdate is mandatory, Enddate is optionally filled or null

I defined a scope 'Active' as follows:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->whereDate('startdate', '<', Carbon::now())->whereDate('enddate', '>', Carbon::now());
    }
```

Bat as you can see this works fine when the enddate is filled (with a date in the future, but how can I add the condition that my startdate is earlier than today, and the enddate is null.

I assume there is a proper solution, but I could not find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
   return $query->where(function($q) {
         $q->where(function($q) {
               $q->whereDate('startdate', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                 ->whereDate('enddate', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateString());
         })->orWhere(function($q) {
               $q->whereDate('startdate', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                 ->whereNull('enddate');
         });
    });
}
```

but because in both scenarios startdate should be in past you can use:

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
   return $query->whereDate('startdate', '<', Carbon::now()->toDateString())
                ->where(function($q) {
                     $q->whereDate('enddate', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateString());
                       ->orWhereNull('enddate');
                  });
          });
}
```

Comment: I prefer the second solution! I implemented this one and worked perfect. Only one small issue: there is one semicolon too many, in the line starting with $q

Comment: Thnx all for thinking about a solution

Answer (score 0):

You should use a parameted scoped

```
public function scopeActive($query, $param)
{
 if(isset($param)) return $query->whereDate('startdate', '<', Carbon::now())->whereDate('enddate', '>', $param);
return $query->whereDate('startdate', '<', Carbon::now());

}
```

[Local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes)